# C#, WinForms Settings

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

У меня возник вопрос, как же можно сделать пользовательскую настройку для приложения. У меня существует несколько форм. При первоначальном запуске приложения, появляется окно настройки, чтоб пользователь мог настроить для себя. Как после этого будет настроен, появится главное окно. Если в том же в ПК, и открыть снова тот же приложение, то открывает только главное окно, а окно настройки больше не будет использован, до самого конца. Пока приложение не будет удален с ПК.

Не предлагать конфигурационный файл XML, bin. Только с помощью ***Settings***

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Settings и есть конфигурационный файл XML. Заведите там параметр, после заполнения установите его, если параметр установлен, то форму не запускать.

Comment: Так же там можно указать как сохранять параметр: для одного пользователя либо для всех пользователей на одном компьютере. Вызов: `Properties.Settings.Default.Переменная; ` Ну а записать в `Properties.Settings` в папке с проектом.

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса, вы не можете убрать условие по которому открывается окно настроек и открывать его безусловно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начиная с .NET Framework 2.0 очень легко работать с настройками приложения. У настроек есть 4 свойства:

1. `Name` - ну тут очевидно :D
2. `Type` - тип данных, представляющий настройку
3. `Scope` - уровень доступа настройки (Application / User), настройка на уровне приложения считается важной и влияет на работу приложения в целом, а пользовательская больше для изменения внешнего вида и тому подобного.
4. `Value` - ну тут тоже очевидно :D

Настройки уровня User имеют rw доступ во время исполнения, а Application только r.

---

***Как добавить настройку??? Легко!***

Project>[ProjectName]>Properties>Settings
Ну а дальше вполне интуитивно понятно :D

---

***Как использовать их в коде??? Легче лёгкого!***
Просто обращаетесь к `Properties.Settings.Default.[SettingName]` и оно вернёт вам `Value` типа, который вы указали при создании.
***Вот и всё!***